# FOSS Gratis Windows SSH client that allows saving passwords

Tags: gratis, open-source, remote-access, desktop-client, ssh

I'm looking for a FOSS Gratis (payless) Windows SSH client that allows saving passwords.

As for now I'm using Putty that doesn't allow saving passwords (rather, only usernames) but I'm looking for one that does indeed save password as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fork of PuTTy named [KiTTy](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/), which contains additional features including password saving.